# DHCP is not working in VMware player v.7.0

Tags: vmware-player

I'm stuck with making DHCP work in VMware Player (v 7.0.0 build 2305329)
I have two VMs:

- Windows 2003 Server - DHCP server
- Windows XP 32 bit - DHCP client

Host OS: Windows 7 Ent, 64 bit SP1

Both VMs connected to "LAN segment 1". They can ping each other if I set static IPs. But if I change Windows XP VM to obtain IP automatically it never receives an IP. (It gets 169.254.x.x)
Windows firewall is disabled on guest and host.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This IP (169.254.x.x) belongs to APIPA range which activates when there is no DHCP in the network .. I think you need to check the settings of your DHCP Server (if you're trying to build a domain, you need to authorize the DHCP server in the domain.

Comment: Adnan, yes the server is authorised